# Disable Default Save Image Option In Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I hover hold on an image on mobile following options appears:

1. Save Image
2. Open Image
3. Open Image in new tab.

How can I disable these options?

I googled and got the below code which is not working

```
.disableSave {
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  -webkit-touch-callout:none;
}
```

Comment: "on mobile" - What OS? What browser?

Comment: i use samsung grand.... android

Comment: That answered none of my questions. 

You're using Samsung. So I figure you're using Android? What version of android? And on Android, do you use the stock android browser or something else?

Comment: i am looking for generalized solution not for particular android...........i gues above solution works for ios

Comment: I know, but what did you test it on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple solution.

For iOS, use the following:

```
.disableSave {
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -webkit-touch-callout:none;
}
```

For Android, use:

```
oncontextmenu="return false;";
```

Comment: Can I use the `.disableSave` class in the `<body>` element? I need to put it in a Wordpress component where I can't add a custom class. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

I used the following CSS and disabled image select + save in mobile and desktop browsers.

```
img {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Things like this are tricky, because when your phone / browser loads the page, it will download the images, e.g. user will have all the images in cache anyways, usually functions using right click can be disabled with JS, however there is no full-proof way of actually disabling right click functionality, on a phone however, you can set the image as `background-image` which basicly if you hold down on it, won't trigger a download, and since there is no developermode for phones, they can't simply inspect element either to get the image source (The exception to that are iOS devices when coupled with a mac using safari).